# Внести изменения в файл и снова залить

Tags: git, git-commit, git-clone

Есть удаленный репозиторий  `http://<username>@site.com/gerrit/p/kontakt` - здесь должна быть одна ветка `master` в которой лежит один файл `test` а в этой папке есть пустой проект.

**Цель: внести изменения и обратно залить.**

Клонировал:

```
> git clone http://<username>@site.com/gerrit/p/kontakt
```

После чего терминале появился надпись типа `name@Name ~ (Master)`,
Мне нужно открыть пустой проект к-й находится в файле `test`, как мне это сделать?

P.S. (Что-то совневаюсь что я правильно клонировал), прочитал документации, пока все еще темный лес.

P.S. Хотел узнать на какой ветке я нахожусь `git branch` - никаких движений и еще создал Репозиторий у себя на диске `С:\User\Name\.git` (почему то без имени получилось)

P.S. И еще не могу переключится на .git

Comment: Выражайтесь, пожалуйста, яснее. Поток сознания какой-то...

Comment: Поток сознания? а как мне узнать это?)

Comment: Не трогайте `.git` напрямую, вам туда не надо. Осознайте смысл трех сущностей: working copy, staging area и repository, и все придет на свои места.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понял что надо осознавать. А можно ли находясь на ветке "Master" создать ветку у себя на компе?

Comment: да, можно:

    git checkout -b some_new_branch

Comment: `test` это был всё-таки файл или папка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по возникающему количеству вопросов: [Git на пальцах](http://habrahabr.ru/post/68341/). Но, для начала, я бы советовал [это](http://githowto.com/ru). За 6 часов можно многому научится в Git.

Comment: Спасибо, читаю ваши ссылки. 
Да. вы правы за 6 часов можно многому научится в git, но мне пока туманно

Comment: Zhukov Roman, а не подскажете как выйти из ветки master? Все прорыл ответа не нашел(

Comment: @bemulima, выйти куда?

Comment: просто выйти - нельзя да так делать? Есть другая ветка к-я я в ручную создал(на компе) а у нее почему то нет имени т.е. создана папка ".get", туда хоть можно переключится? 
я просто переживаю что нибудь испортить на удаленном репозиторий.

Comment: Да, нельзя. Вы не создали ветку, вы создали какую-то папку. Я бы советовал вам с нуля и вдумчиво перечитать руководство по git. Ветки создаются командой git branch или git checkout. Не волнуйтесь, если вы не будете использовать команду git push, то ничего в удаленный репозиторий не попадет.

Comment: Мне не нравится то что я сейчас нахожусь в ветке "Master" - это напригает и мандражирует, я даже перезагрузил комп чтоб от туда выйти:) но этого почему то не случилось. Ваши ссылки то что надо, спасибо.

Comment: Вы всегда будете в какой-то ветке, работая с репозиторием. Ветка существующая по-умолчанию имеет имя `master`. Вы можете переключиться на другую ветку, ответвив ее от `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю полную инструкцию на всякий случай.

**Скачать/клонировать:**

Перейти в папку, в которой вам будет удобно иметь репозиторий, а потом клонировать (вы всё верно сделали).

```
cd path/to/my/repo
git clone http://<username>@site.com/gerrit/p/kontakt
```

**Внести изменения**

Любым редактором. После того, как внесли, добавляйте их [командой `git add`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472). Например, мы меняли что-то в папке `test`, находящейся в корне репозитория. Так можно добавить всё, что меняли в этой папке:

```
git add test
```

или точный путь к файлу:

```
git add test/index.html
```

**Снова залить:**

```
git push
```

Дополнительные вопросы:

> Хотел узнать на какой ветке я нахожусь

[Команда `git branch`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) показывает звездочку напротив этой ветки:

```
$ git branch
* alt
  master
```

> И еще не могу переключится на .git

Это скрытая папка, в которой находится хранилище данных Git. Вам не нужно работать с ней напрямую, даже напротив — не меняйте там ничего, пока не знаете точно, что вы делаете.