# В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?

Tags: git, git-add, git-reset

Есть разные способы добавить все измененные файлы в индекс репозитория Git. В чем разница и зачем столько способов?

```
git add .
git add *
git add -u
git add -A
git add --all
git add --no-all
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Давайте обозначим категории файлов, которые вообще можно добавлять. Будем использовать те же обозначения, что и в выводе команды `git status -s`:

`M` - (**m**odified) отслеживаемые, изменились с прошлого коммита, еще не добавлены
`D` - (**d**eleted) отслеживаемые, удалены после прошлого коммита, еще не добавлены
`?` - (untracked) неотслеживаемые, не запрещены к добавлению
`!` - (ignored) неотслеживаемые, запрещены к добавлению (например, в `.gitignore`)

## Параметры и аргументы

Первое различие  — в том, что `.` — это путь (аргумент), а всё остальное — параметры. Те и другие не исключают друг друга и возможны их сочетания.

## Использование абсолютных `:/` и относительных `.` путей с командой `add`

Путь `.` обозначает текущую директорию, т.е. ту, в которой была запущена команда.

> [Начиная с Git версии 2.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L19-L30), поведение команды `add` приведено в соответствие с поведением `commit` и других комманд. Теперь `.` обозначает не всю рабочую область (working tree), а текущий путь в этой области.

Таким образом, если вы выполняете команду `add` не в корневой директории проекта (той, где лежит `.git/`), то будет обработано содержимое только текущей директории.

Чтобы явным образом дать указание Git работать со всей рабочей областью, используйте `:/`:

```
# работает одинаково из любой директории, добавляет всю рабочую область
git add :/

# путь относительно корневой директории
git add :/path/to/files/

# работает только в текущей директории
cd test
git add .
# эквивалентно этому:
git add :/test

# путь относительно текущей директории
cd test
git add ./path
# эквивалентно этому:
git add :/test/path
```

Если не указан никакой путь к добавляемым файлам, то большинство команд работает во *всей рабочей области*, а `git add` и `git add --no-all` просто не работают.

## Сводная таблица

[image: сводная таблица]

## О функционале команд подробно

---

```
git add .
git add '*'
```

Git версии 2.0+ просматривает *текущую папку* и добавляет файлы `M`, `D`, `?`.
Git версии 1.х просматривает всю *рабочую область* и добавляет файлы `M`, `D`.

Если `'*'` дается в кавычках, то обрабатывать его будет Git и это эквивалентно `git add .`. Исключение: из-под cmd.exe `git add '*'` не сработает, используйте `git add .` или `git add *`.

---

```
git add --no-all :/
git add --ignore-removal :/
```

Эта команда в Git v. 2.0+ работает как `git add .` в Git v. 1.x, то есть добавляет измененные и новые файлы `M`, `?` во всей рабочей области. Для этой команды обязательно указывать путь.

```
git add --no-all . #добавляет измененные и новые файлы в *текущей директории*
git add --no-all path1/ path2/ # добавляет измененные и новые файлы в путях *относительно текущей директории*
```

---

```
git add -u
git add -update
```

Git обновляет (update) статус уже отслеживаемых файлов т.е. `M`, `D`.

---

```
git add -A
git add --all
git add --no-ignore-removal
```

Эти варианты эквивалентны и добавляют `M`, `D`, `?`.

Без точки — из всей рабочей области:

`git add -A` = `git add -A :/` = `git add :/` + `git add -u`

С точкой — только текущий путь:

`git add -A .` = `git add .` + `git add -u .`

---

```
 git add *
```

> Этот синтаксис лучше не использовать, и вот почему:

При этой команде **shell** (или bash или другая командная оболочка) просматривает рабочую область и отдает Git список файлов на добавление. Система сработает таким образом, что будут найдены абсолютно все не-скрытые файлы, находящиеся в заданном корне.  Вы можете посмотреть на этот список, выполнив `echo *`. ( Исключение: из-под cmd.exe `git add *` работает так же как `git add '*'` на shell/bash. )

Произойдет следующее (здесь мы видим сразу несколько причин не использовать `add *`):

1. Добавятся не изменившиеся с прошлого коммита файлы. Git спокойно и молча "прожует" этот запрос, не влияющий на индекс.
2. Будут добавлены в индекс файлы в не-скрытых папках `M`,`?`.
3. Не будут добавлены файлы в скрытых папках. `.M`, `.?`
4. Не будут добавлены удаленные файлы `D`.
5. Если будут захвачены игнорируемые файлы `!`, то будет попытка их добавить. **Git отменит всю операцию** и покажет сообщение об ошибке.

## Зачем столько способов

Разнообразие параметров (`-u`, `-A`, `--no-all`) нужно для того, чтобы можно было добавлять разные группы файлов. Конкретно `--no-all .` было добавлено для того, чтобы реализовывать старое поведение `add .` в версиях 1.х.

Похоже, что несмотря на это, Git не позволяет добавлять конкретные группы файлов одной командой (см. сводную таблицу в начале).

Тонкости в использовании `.` и `:/` нужны для того, чтобы каждую команду можно было выполнять как на всю рабочую область, так и на конкретную подпапку.