# Проверка файлов на измененность GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-clone

Есть репозиторий на GitHub, в котором коммитов никто не делал несколько недель.

За эти несколько недель было внесено очень-очень много правок, но все напрямую через sftp на сайте продакшена.

На нем есть папка .git. Копия всех файлов вместе с этой папкой есть у меня на компьютере.

Как мне теперь залить в репозиторий все изменения, подобавлять новые файлы и прочее?

Я пока попробовал с помощью коммандной строки и git add. В итоге мне выдало что-то такое:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.*.*' to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Как я понял, это потому что я сгрузил папку `.git` с сервера. Как-то это можно исправить?

И еще выдает много ошибок по файлам типа: warning: `LF will be replaced by CRLF`

Comment: сделайте `cd` в тот каталог, где находится под-каталог `.git` и выполните `git status`. в выводе этой команды будет рассказано, какие файлы изменились, какие были удалены, какие добавлены.

Comment: На рабочей машине git установлен, да. Пользуюсь им через phpstorm вообще.

Comment: `git status` действительно работает. Но как мне теперь выбрать определенные файлы и папки (есть и лишние) и все это вылить в репозиторий?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: что там на винде с CRLF ставится, `core.autocrlf=true`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, автозамена, по идее, не помешает в любой операционной системе. / с *ms/windows* я знаком примерно в той же мере, что и с *apple/osx*: большей частью чисто теоретически.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Для командной строки

Подойдет любая. Через PHPStorm открывается Alt+F12, насколько я помню.

#### 1. Настройка переноса строки

> `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF`

решается настройкой автозамены символов переноса строки.

Для Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf=true
```

#### 2. Получить локальный репозиторий с настроенным удаленным.

> `Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.*.*' to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`
>
> Как я понял, это потому что я сгрузил папку .git с сервера. Как-то это можно исправить?

Просто копировать папку с сервера — не подходит, там другие настройки. Можно пробовать перенастроить, но это чревато проблемами. Быстрый и гарантированный способ — клонировать с удаленного репозитория (в данном случае это GitHub).

Если консоль открыли через PHPstorm, то она откроется прямо в вашем проекте. Если нет — надо перейти в папку проекта.

1. Клонируем проект в новую временную папку, чтобы получить `.git`.

   Ссылку для клонирования можно найти на странице вашего проекта на гитхабе. Обратите внимание: мы указываем путь, куда будет клонироваться проект. Параметр `-n` заставляет Git только клонировать папку, но не «разворачивать» из нее файлы.

   ```
   mkdir ../temp_git
   git clone -n https://github.com/YourName/project-name.git ../temp_git
   ```
2. Теперь заменим ту папку .git, которая у вас скопирована с сервера, на ту, которую мы получили клонированием. Если можете привычным способом удалить в проекте и перенести из клонированного — делайте так. Если нет — вот инструкция для командной строки.

   ```
   # удаляем местную папку .git, ранее полученную копированием с сервера
   rm -Rf .git
   # переносим к себе новую клонированную с верными настройками
   mv ../temp_git/.git .
   # удаляем временную папку
   rm -Rf ../temp_git
   ```

#### 3. Добавить изменения и залить их на удаленный репозиторий

1. Переходим в ту папку, где лежит ваш .git. Переходим в ту ветку, в которую вы хотите эти изменения сохранить (зависит от принятого у вас рабочего процесса).

   ```
   cd path/to/project/
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Смотрим на то, какие изменения произошли

   ```
   git status -s
   ```

   - M — измененные файлы
   - D — удаленные
   - ? — новые файлы и папки.
3. Подумайте, все ли они подлежат контролю версий. Возможно, там есть какой-нибудь хлам вроде временных файлов. Если они всегда будут ненужными — добавляйте их в `.gitignore`. Это позволит вам добавлять целые папки, фильтруя игнорируемые файлы.
4. Дальше если изменения можно разделить на логические блоки — придумайте эти блоки. Если нет — считайте что блок один. Для каждого блока:

   1. [Добавьте соответствующие ему файлы в индекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472)

      ```
      git add folder/
      git add *.jpg
      ...
      ```
   2. Сделайте коммит с сообщением, которое отражает смысл блока

      ```
      git commit -m'relevant message'
      ```
5. Проверьте, что у вас получилось и всё ли вы добавили. При необходимости — к пункту 4.

   ```
   git log
   git status
   ```
6. Можно заливать на удаленный репозиторий.

   ```
   git push
   ```

#### Про развертывание и Git

По–хорошему, коммиты в Git нужно делать часто. Каждый раз, когда вы заливаете что-то через sftp, мог бы предваряться коммитом.

Поскольку у вас есть репозиторий Git, вы можете использовать его для развертывания сайта. Обратите внимание на способы без репозитория на сервере — они наиболее надежны. [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)

Comment: Я пока попробовал с помощью коммандной строки и `git add`. 
В итоге мне выдало что-то такое: 
`Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.*.*' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Как я понял, это потому что я сгрузил папку .git с сервера. Как-то это можно исправить?

И еще выдает много ошибок по файлам типа: `warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF`

Comment: Да, могу. Это windows, оно у меня автоматом их отображает.

Comment: Я выполнил команду `git config core.autocrlf true`, не показывает ничего.
И я таки разобрался, в репозиторий все загрузилось. Спасибо.

Comment: @EugeneSalitrinsky: значительно упростил инструкцию по клонированию — посмотрите, вдруг еще раз понадобится. Уточнения из ваших комментариев добавил в вопрос и ответ.

Comment: @EugeneSalitrinsky: кстати, еще одно уточнение. «На нем есть папка .git. » это на сайте продакшена прямо? Она там как и зачем? Лучше там ее не хранить, это чревато проблемами. Опять-таки, тут есть ссылка: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472