# GitHub не видит класс

Tags: git

Git не видит, что был добавлен класс и игнорирует его при комите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поправить?

Comment: Подробнее о том, как пользоваться `git add`: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде чем сделать коммит, следует добавить файл в индекс командой `git add <File.ext>`
Также разгадка может крыться в содержимом `.gitignore`

Comment: git add . помог. Спс.