# Разница в использовании git cmd и git bash под windows

Tags: git, git-bash, git-cmd

Установил Git for Windows с сайта https://git-scm.com/
После установки есть возможность запускать две консоли - `git cmd` и `git bash`.
Я так понимаю, что `git cmd` - командная строка windows, а `git bash` - командная строка linux. Первые шаги при использовании не выявили существенных отличий в работе обоих. Заметил лишь, что в `git bash` есть удобное и достаточно приятное выделение цветом, а также подсказки для команд при двойном нажатии Tab.
Наверняка есть более глобальные отличия между `git cmd` и `git bash`, которые заставят любителя cmd запускать bash. Вопрос: какие? Ибо тогда зачем в сборку для windows добавлять альтернативу cmd?

Comment: из того, что я знаю - это использование glob (cmd вряд ли поймет `git add **/*.cpp`). Также в bash доступные многие удобные утилиты, которых нет в cmd.
И конечно же, многие мануалы по настройке гита будут легко настраиваться с баш консоли, но не cmd (придется правильно угадывать пути и тому подобное).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не бывает `git cmd` или `git bash`. Есть только сервисные утилиты, а точнее одна сервисная утилита с разными именами: `git-cmd.exe` и `git-bash.exe`.

Оба эти exe-шника делают

1. Инициализация переменных окружения (PATH, и пр.)
2. Запуск терминала.

Разница между ними только одна - **по умолчанию** `git-bash.exe` запускает терминал `mintty` с `bash` внутри. `git-cmd.exe` запускает стандартный терминал Windows с `cmd.exe`. Более того, `git-cmd.exe` имеет ключик `--command=...` с помощью которого можно запустить bash вместо cmd при желании.

`git.exe` это самостоятельная программа рядом с которой лежат все необходимые утилиты из пакета msys (например `ls`, `vim`, `sed`, и прочая), а недостающие утилиты можно "доставить" с помощью `pacman`. Предполагаемая проблема с "путями" не имеет оснований - все команды выполняет сам гит.
`git add **/*.cpp` будет обрабатываться самим гитом.

Реальные различия:

- Из командной строки cmd.exe несколько меняется синтаксис, т.к. `^` это управляющий символ cmd.exe. Например, вместо `git.exe rebase -i 2385397^1` нужно писать `git.exe rebase -i 2385397^^1`.
- Маски файлов, вроде вышеописанного `git add *.cpp` не "разворачиваются" в список файлов, то есть аргументы передаются без изменений и git самостоятельно выполняет поиск подходящих файлов. В итоге мы имеем ошибочное поведение когда `git add *.cpp` добавляет файлы из подкаталогов.
- В консоли cmd.exe (если только она не в [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) запущена) нельзя использовать 256 цветов в Vim.

Вот наверное и всё.

Comment: Похоже, что нет ни одной причины предпочесть `git-cmd.exe`?

Comment: называется "не разобрался, но критикую". Говоря о путях, я имел ввиду то, что в большинстве инструкций для гита они указываются в юникс стиле, и bash.exe (с окружением) их прекрасно поймет. А вот cmd - нет.

С глобами не все тоже так прозрачно. Обычно баш сам раскрывает их, но в большинстве случаев гит сам раскрывает пути точно также. И это очень прозрачно.

Comment: @KoVadim Можно тогда пример команд с "путями", которые не будут выполнены из git-cmd.exe?

Comment: здесь есть пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431839/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-git-add-add-a-add-u-%D0%B8-add

Comment: я вот с путями столкнулся в противоположную сторону - в винде из проводника копируешь путь (C:\Program Files) и работает в cmd, а для bash старайся меняй на /c/blabla/ - все \ на / - задержка работы.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov В ConEmu при вставке путей в консоль происходит автоматическое преобразование формата.

Comment: @Maximus, правильно я понял, что эта утилита не из пакета гита? (чтобы понятно было читающим вопрос-ответ...)

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov А про какую из упомянутых в ответе утилит вы спрашиваете? ;) ConEmu самостоятельная программа, но насколько я помню, в гите есть пакет с ней.