# Клонирование проекта в Android Studio в локальный репозиторий

Tags: git, android-studio, git-clone

При работе с Git в Android Studio возникла следующая проблема:

Хотелось бы добавить локальный репозиторий, например, на флэшку. Т.е., я хочу клонировать проект с одного локального репозитория (на ПК) на другой (на флэшку) (например, чтобы если с ПК что-то случится, можно было этот проект взять с флэшки). При этом потом при внесении изменений в проект необходимо, чтобы каждый из репозиториев можно было обновить.

В интернете много информации про то, как это сделать для серверов, т.е. клонировать текущий репозиторий с проектом, например, в GitHub.

А как это сделать для локального репозитория? Каким образом можно клонировать проект из одного локального репозитория в другой в Android Studio?

Содержимое файла *config* в папке *.git* которая создается после клонирования в локальный репозиторий:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0

filemode = false

bare = false

logallrefupdates = true

symlinks = false

ignorecase = true

hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]

url = D:\\workDinar\\Android\\GitExperiment

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]

remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Кратко: bare-репозиторий на флешке, `git remote add backup path/to/repo `,

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за ответ. С командной строкой вроде все понятно. А есть ли возможность это сделать встроенными средствами Android Studio ?

Comment: вряд ли, не сталкивался.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, почему тогда на удаленный репозиторий можно клонировать (например GitHub, в интернет есть статьи на эту тему) а в локальный нет ?  Разницы ведь по сути никакой.

Comment: Если в студии клонировать на локальный носитель по схеме, как на удаленный, но указав вместо URL путь на диске, то почему то клонируется только папка /.git, а весь проект (сами файлы) не клонируется (то же и с командой clone из *VCS -> Git -> Clone*), по крайней мере у меня не получилось, но возможно истина где то рядом

Comment: @pavlofff, у меня тоже самое было. В новом локальном репозитории только Git файл был после клонирования.

Comment: @pavlofff наверное это bare-репозиторий. В нем только данные, а файлов нет. Он не предназначен для коммитов, только push в него можно.

Comment: @pavlofff, foxis, а какой именно url вы указывали при клонировании? в *ms/windows* надо что-то вроде `file:///C:/путь/к/каталогу/` (вероятно, вариант `file:///C:/путь/к/каталогу/.git` — не подходит (или наоборот)).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, url указывал обычный к примеру **D:\Work\SomeRep**. Но почему-то файлы не копируются. Возможно конечно надо вводить в том стиле, который вы рекомендуете ( _file:///C:/путь/к/каталогу/_ ). Надо будет попробовать.

Comment: @foxis, посмотрите ответы к вопросу, ссылку на который я приводил в ответе: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2519933/4827341 // там разные примеры приведены.

Comment: @pavlofff, foxis, на тестовой машине с *gnu/linux*, **которую не жалко**, установил *android studio*, склонировал [образцовый проект](https://github.com/codepath/intro_android_demo.git) в каталог `/путь/к/репозиторию` и прекрасно сделал в *android studio* клон этого репозитория, указав в качестве *url-а* путь к этому каталогу (`/путь/к/репозиторию`). так что под *ms/windows* вопрос только в правильном *url-е*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я всякие пробовал пути указывать - и обычный Windows, и начиная с file:/ , и слеши в разные стороны и все, какие есть способы указания пути - копирует только папку */.git*. Я думаю, если бы проблема была в пути, то и эта папка бы не склонировалась.

Comment: @pavlofff, foxis, судя по содержимому выложенного в тексте вопроса файла `.git/config`, с репозиторием всё в порядке. ну, если *android studio* не делает `git checkout` после клонирования, то это просто «баг» этой программы, о котором стоит сообщить её разработчикам.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо большое за помощь, с клонированием в Android Studio теперь более менее стало понятно.

Answer (score 2):

клонировать локальный репозиторий, как и удалённый, можно абсолютно стандартной командой:

```
$ git clone url-репозитория
```

- в *unix-like* операционных системах *url-репозитория* представляет собой просто путь к репозиторию: `/путь/к/каталогу/.git` или даже без последней части: `/путь/к/каталогу`.
- в **не**-*unix-like* операционных системах [чуть сложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519933/4827341): *url-репозитория*, видимо, должен выглядеть примерно как: `file:///C:/путь/к/каталогу/.git` (или `file:///C:/путь/к/каталогу`).

---

предполагаю, что ровно то же самое можно проделать не только в программе *android studio*, но и в любой другой программе, способной выполнить программу *git* с командой *clone* и нужными параметрами. надо просто указать правильный *url-репозитория*.

---

**обновление**

вот [инструкция с картинками](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-import-git-dependent-projects-to-Android-studio), какие кнопки в *android studio* надо нажимать для клонирования произвольного репозитория. картинки здесь приведу для сохранности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я имел в виду что bare-репозиторий студия скорее не умеет создавать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я вас понял. да, нормальная схема при наличии двух и более клонов — клонировать их не друг из друга, а из bare-клона. но на первых порах автору вопроса, по-моему, лучше не забивать голову подобной информацией. впрочем, для других читателей, вероятно, лучше этот момент упомянуть. вы не помните, может быть у нас тут уже есть ответ, в котором такая схема разжёвана?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вы правы. Суть то вопроса как раз в том чтобы клонировать встроенными средствами среды разработки Android Studio. А не заморачиваться командной строкой (я понимаю что нужно изучать командную строку, но пока мне хотелось начать с более простого варианта работы с VCS). Если у Android Studio нет нормального инструментария в этом случае я лучше буду пользоваться sourceTree, которая более понятна на мой взгляд. Просто хотелось иметь весь инструментарий в одной программе.

Comment: @foxis, в ответе написано в том числе и по поводу *android studio*. в последнем абзаце. *Если у Android Studio нет нормального инструментария в этом случае я лучше буду пользоваться sourceTree* — формльно его (инструментария) нет ни там ни там. ведь обе упомянутые программы используют программу *git* (в виде исполняемого файла или библиотеки). но обе отлично умеют делать `git clone`, что вам и требуется. так что (с некоторой долей условности) можно сказать, что «подходящий интсрументарий» есть у обеих упомянутых вами программ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, большое спасибо вам за ответ. Вы мне все время говорите пользоваться командной строкой. Я же спрашиваю есть ли в GUI в Android Studio такая функция. К примеру в винде копировать и вставлять файлы можно через командную строку и через GUI. Сейчас получается в командной строке есть эта функция (в нашем случае клонирование), а в GUI это нормально не реализовано. Кстати в sourceTree как раз клонирование адекватно реализовано именно в GUI что выгодно его отличает от Android Studio.

Comment: @foxis, *Вы мне все время говорите пользоваться командной строкой* — не вижу, где я вам такое говорил. *а в GUI это нормально не реализовано* — да реализовано, конечно! вот вам [про клонирование, с картинками](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-import-git-dependent-projects-to-Android-studio). только url репозитория укажите верно, как в ответе написано.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо за ответ. Фишка в том что в статьях которые в сети и в вашем примере в том числе говориться как клонировать в Android Studio во внешний репозиторий. Если те же самые манипуляции сделать с локальным репозиторием, например на флэшке, то файлы почему-то не копируются (_см. комментарии к моему вопросу_).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, попробуйте сделать то, что у вас на картинках с локальным репозиторием (на ПК или на флэшке), У меня к сожалению не получилось.

Comment: @foxis, к сожалению, не могу: у меня нет не только *android studio*, но и даже *ms/windows*. насколько я понял, в указанном каталоге у вас создаётся под-каталог `.git` (с содержимым репозитория), а больше файлов/каталогов не создаётся? приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса содержимое файла `.git/config`, который создаётся при попытке клонирования. это простой текстовый файл.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, выложил содержимое файла _.git/config_ который создается после клонирования в локальный репозиторий.