# Почему файл выделен красным?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Файл выделен красным, произошло это после того, как я выложил два класса калькулятора на GitHub, а при создании этого среда разработки предложила выложить и его, но я отказался.

Как я понимаю, файл подсвечен красным из-за того, что он не связан с гитхабом, т. к. раньше такого не было.
Про подчеркивание красным в JDK знаю, но тут что-то новое.

Подскажите, действительно какая-то ошибка или мое предположение подтвердилось?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: интересует класс Test1

Comment: Правильно понимаете :)

Comment: Владимир, спасибо за ответ и потраченное время)

Comment: Красным подсвечивает файлы, не добавленные в систему контроля версий (в гит в данном случае). Делайте коммит, в окошке коммита ставите галку напротив этого файла в "Unversioned files", он коммитится.

Comment: спасибо, @insolor !)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с индикацией цвета при работе с Git в Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529547/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-git-%d0%b2-android-studio)