# Как не игнорировать файл в игнорируемой папке?

Tags: git, gitignore

У меня есть папка которая игнорируется `app/design/frontend/rwd/` и все её содержимое тоже игнорируется я пару раз сделал `push`.

Но теперь мне нужно создать там файл vendor.xml который игнорировать не надо.

Сделал так:

```
!app/design/frontend/rwd/vendor.xml
```

Но оно всё равно игнорируется! делаю `git status`  но он не отслеживается и `git add app/design/frontend/rwd/vendor.xml` тоже пробовал!

**Что в таком случаи сделать чтоб гит перестал его игнорировать ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Универсальное решение дано [в ответе Юрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544822/181472). Но в данном случае можно не редактировать файл `.gitignore`, а использовать добавление в индекс [с ключом -f](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431840/181472).

```
git add -f app/design/frontend/rwd/vendor.xml
```

Однажды добавленный и сохранённый в коммите, этот файл будет версионироваться и дальше. Если захотите перестать его версионировать:

```
git rm --cached app/design/frontend/rwd/vendor.xml
```

Comment: ♦, спасибо ) помогло

Comment: Но почему исключение в гитигноре не работало?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov не знаю, вроде должно работать. Решение Юрия верное.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот я знал, что придёте, кинете пару команд для `cmd` и всё заработает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну, моё решение- это как стукнуть по телевизору вместо починки. Грубо)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в наших широтах, порой, только так и можно сделать) И надо иметь нефиговый опыт для просчитывания места удара и его силы)))

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте сначала указать игнорирование всех файлов в папке, а потом указать неигнорирование строго определённого файла:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/*
!app/design/frontend/rwd/vendor.xml
```

Подробнее — [в документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).

Comment: IDE подсвечивает как те? что не игнорируются. Но в репозиторий не заливаются

Comment: Попробуйте удалить этот файл, закоммитить а потом снова добавить и закоммитить.

Comment: не видит изменений ни при удалении ни при добавлении этого файла

Comment: @Maybe_V в репозиторий не заливаются - а вы добавляли?