# "Хитрое" игнорирование файлов в git

Tags: git, gitignore

В одном довольно старом проекте, в директории /public встречаются файлы, которые генерируются самим проектом, но все другие файлы нужно взять под версионный контроль. Файлы, которые не нужно добавлять в Git можно записать таким шаблоном: `^[a-z0-9].php$` (регулярка на PHP, ^ - начало строки, $ - конец), но вместе с тем есть несколько файлов: `index.php`, `main.php`, etc, которые мониторить нужно, но они же попадают по шаблон `^[a-z0-9].php$`. Просьба подсказать, как можно написать такой сценарий в `.gitignore`?

Comment: Посмотрите на решения из вопроса [Как не игнорировать файл в игнорируемой папке?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544817). Там почти та же задача решается, но в более общем виде — выборочно добавить файлы, когда папка уже целиком добавлена в `.gitignore`. У вас тоже впоследствии могут появиться новые файлы в `/public`, которые нужно будет версионировать.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы исключить какой-то файл из игнорируемых, достаточно добавить маску совпадения с префиксом `!`:

```
# игнорировать все файлы и поддиректории
*
# но сохранить сам .gitignore
!.gitignore
```

Единственная проблема, с которой вы можете столкнуться - это сохранение файлов внутри поддиректории игнорированной директории:

```
*
# не сработает, потому что потомки subdirectory не будут распознаны
!subdirectory/file
```

Тогда приходится прибегать к хакам

```
*
!subdirectory
subdirectory/*
!subdirectory/file
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что было нужно, но спасибо за полезную информацию про поддиректории и воскл. знак!

Answer (score 2):

Пока ждал ответ - разобрался сам.
Сначала нужно вручную добавить все нужные файлы и директории в индекс:

```
$ git add public/dir1/
$ git add public/dir2/
$ git add public/index.php
$ git add public/main.php
$ git add public/etc.php
```

А потом в .gitignore добавить строку:

```
public/*.php
```

И все... все оказалось намного проще, чем представлялось на первый взгляд.