# В gitignore не работает инвертирование правила

Tags: git, gitignore

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, почему файл `SLTestCommonLibs-0.1.tar.gz` не попадает в индекс.

В gitignore написано:

```
**/dist/
!CommonLibs/dist/SLTestCommonLibs-0.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Если это разовая операция, то можно сделать так: [`git add --force CommonLibs/dist/SLTestCommonLibs-0.1.tar.gz`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544833/181472)

Answer (score 1):

сделайте игноринг файлов внутри папки, но не ее самой:

```
**/dist/*
```