# Папка node_modules попадает в индекс GIT

Tags: node.js, вёрстка, git, npm

Папка находится и в глобальном .gitignore (раньше такой проблемы не было), и в локальном, в папке проекта:

```
!/static/remake/node_modules/
/static/remake/node_modules/
```

Удаляешь папку из индекса (`git rm -r --cached node_modules`), но при последующем `git add` она опять там оказывается. Что за напасть такая и как от неё избавиться?

Comment: А зачем там строка `!/static/remake/node_modules/`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это на всякий случай, чтобы GIT не отслеживал изменения там. Это уже эксперименты, и без неё всё равно добавляет.

Comment: Зря, это наоброт отмена игнорирования.

Comment: И наверняка проблема у вас такая: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432895/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin Хм, действительно, я спутал с untracked, когда читал про неё. Удаление строки помогло. По ссылке читал уже, говорю ж, из индекса удалял.
А для чего тогда добавлять эту строку, если никакого смысла она не несёт с точки зрения функционала?

Comment: Для инвертирования игнора: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544817/181472