# GIt add . не добавляет файлы к комиту

Tags: git, git-add

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь добавить файлы к коммиту на bitbucket, на что получаю следующее:

```
staralex@kvazar:/var/www/develblog/develblogproject$ git add .

staralex@kvazar:/var/www/develblog/develblogproject$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   vendor/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget
    modified:   vendor/behat/gherkin
    modified:   vendor/bibldev/yii2-searchwidget
    modified:   vendor/cebe/markdown
    modified:   vendor/codeception/base
    modified:   vendor/costa-rico/yii2-images
    modified:   vendor/doctrine/instantiator
    modified:   vendor/doctrine/lexer
    modified:   vendor/fzaninotto/faker
    modified:   vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working     directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/myclabs/deep-copy (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phar-io/manifest (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-common (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpspec/php-diff (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpspec/prophecy (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/php-timer (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/phpunit (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/psr/http-message (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/psr/log (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/diff (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/environment (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/exporter (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/global-state (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/object-enumerator (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/object-reflector (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/recursion-context (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/resource-operations (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/sebastian/version (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/studio-42/elfinder (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/browser-kit (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/console (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/css-selector (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/debug (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/dom-crawler (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/finder (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/translation (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/symfony/yaml (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/webmozart/assert (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiimaker/yii2-social-share (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiisoft/yii2 (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiisoft/yii2-composer (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiisoft/yii2-faker (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (modified content)
```

Не помогает ни `git add --all`, ни `git add --force`,
Да и в .gitignore никаких правил на директорию vendor нет.
При git push на bitbucket заливаются все файлы, за исключением отмеченных.

Comment: Выглядит как будто у вас в проекте полно сабмодулей, и в них зачем-то сделаны изменения...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй использовать маску `*` для всех файлов

```
git add *
```

Нашёл подробное описание тут [В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431839/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-git-add-add-a-add-u-%D0%B8-add), кто-то на славу постарался )

Comment: Аналогичный результат

Comment: @Biblbrox, я поправил свой ответ

Comment: @Biblbrox короче, мне Ванга подсказывает, что добавление параметра `-a` при коммите решит все твои проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Каталоги это не корень сайта.

У меня тоже в папках vendor нашлись папки .git, по причине этого файлы не загружались на bitbucket.

```
Удалить папки:
vendor/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/.git/
vendor/behat/gherkin/.git/
```

...
и заработает.

Answer (score -4):

***Команда ниже удалит Ваш репозиторий, не делайте этого, если не уверены или у Вас нет резервной копии***

---

Вообщем, все заработало после того, как я удалил .git файлы в этих каталогах(не знаю что они там делали):

```
sudo rm -Rf .git
```

Comment: Вы удалили сам репозиторий,  сердечно поздравляю.