# Как в git добавить новые локальные файлы?

Tags: git

Здравствуйте очень плохо разбираюсь в гит. Ситуация такая. У меня есть папка в ней 2 папки в 1-й проект с исходными файлами header, во 2-й сборка этого проекта с тоже нужными файлами. Так вот общая папка загружена на git-hub. У моего проекта были глюки и я вынужден был удалить файлы во 2 папке из общей папки. Когда собрал во 2 папку добавился совершенно другой файл. При коммите эти файлы не обновились, добавить эти файлы к проекту тоже не выходит. Что мне делать?

Comment: Вот мне кажется Вам это может помочь
[https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче надо было когда я файл добавлял две \ ставить вот так:

```
git add -f  C:\\myrepo\\dir2\\*
```

Comment: Ключ `-f` в `add -f` —  это уже признак того, что что-то не в порядке в датском королевстве. Просто `add` не работает?

Comment: Не. Я ж говорю я полный нуб в этом git. Наверно что то не правильно изначально сделал.

Comment: Подозреваю, что ответ на ваш вопрос есть здесь: [В чем разница между git add ., add -A, add -u и add *?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431839/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-git-add-add-a-add-u-%d0%b8-add/431840#431840). Хотя я так и не понял, что там за файл у вас появился.

Comment: Ааа, погодите, вроде понял. Если у вас есть какие-то файлы, которые не добавляются, значит они заигнорированы с помощью файла `.gitignore`. Это наверняка было сделано специально, чтобы вы не коммитили логи сборки, скомпилированные файлы и прочее, что получается при сборке проекта и что **не нужно коммитить**.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не надо быть таким категоричным. У меня вот на проекте в .gitignore добавлены .png файлы. Потому периодически приходится добавлять иконки именно через `-f`

Comment: Кстати, а такая `git add C:/myrepo/dir2/*` конструкция работает?